# Ошибка с библиотекой blockcypher

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, с ошибкой. Вот код:

```
import blockcypher

class check():
    # считываем данные из файла с текущими данными
    with open(r'current_data.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as cur_fl:
        # получим список всех строк
        cur_data_lines = cur_fl.readlines()
        # на основе списка создадим словарь ключ:значение
        cur_data_dict = {
            ln.split(';')[0]:ln.split(';')[1]  # разделение строки по ';' - левая часть в ключ, правая в значение
            for ln in cur_data_lines
        }
    # то же самое, но для файла с предыдущими значениями
    with open(r'prev_data.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as prev_fl:
        prev_data_lines = prev_fl.readlines()
        prev_data_dict = {ln.split(';')[0]:ln.split(';')[1] for ln in prev_data_lines}

    # обход по циклу всех пар ключ:значение из файла с текущими данными
    for k, v in cur_data_dict.items():
        # если ключ есть в предыдущем файле и значение не равно предыдущему
        if (k in prev_data_dict.keys()) and (v != prev_data_dict[k]):
            balance = blockcypher.get_total_balance(k)
            if k[0:2] == '0x':
                balance_in_eth = balance / 2864966.76
                # prev_balance_in_eth = blockcypher.from_satoshis(prev_balance, 'eth')
                # telegram_bot.send_message(f'Изменение количества транзакций в адресе {k}. Значение изменилось на {v}.'+"\n"+'Текущий баланс ' + balance_in_eth + ' ETH')
                print("---ETH")
                print(k)
                print(v)
                print(balance_in_btc)
            else:
                balance_in_btc = balance / 100000000
                # prev_balance_in_btc = blockcypher.from_satoshis(prev_balance, 'btc')
                # telegram_bot.send_message(f'Изменение количества транзакций в адресе {k}. Значение изменилось на {v}.'+"\n"+'Текущий баланс ' + balance_in_btc + ' BTC')
                print("---BTC")
                print(k)
                print(v)
                print(balance_in_btc)
            # переносим значения текущего файла в файл с предыдущими данными
            # открывает файл с предыдущими данными на запись
    with open(r'prev_data.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as prev_fl:
        # открываем файл с текущими данными на чтение
        with open(r'current_data.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as cur_fl:
            # записываем в файл с предыдущими файлами то, что прочли из файла с текущими
            prev_fl.write(cur_fl.read())
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/task/storage.py", line 22, in <module>
    class check():
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/task/storage.py", line 46, in check
    balance = blockcypher.get_total_balance(k)
  File "D:\Other\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\blockcypher\api.py", line 310, in get_total_balance
    return get_address_overview(address=address,
  File "D:\Other\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\blockcypher\api.py", line 292, in get_address_overview
    assert is_valid_address_for_coinsymbol(b58_address=address,
AssertionError
```

Потом добавил try/except вот так:

```
for k, v in cur_data_dict.items():
        # если ключ есть в предыдущем файле и значение не равно предыдущему
        if (k in prev_data_dict.keys()) and (v != prev_data_dict[k]):
            try:
                balance = blockcypher.get_total_balance(k)
            except:
                print('error_in_get_total_balance')
            if k[0:2] == '0x':
                balance_in_eth = balance / 2864966.76
                try:
                    print("---ETH")
                    print(k)
                    print(v)
                    print(balance_in_eth)
                except:
                    print('error_in_print')
            else:
                balance_in_btc = balance / 100000000
                try:
                    print("---BTC")
                    print(k)
                    print(v)
                    print(balance_in_btc)
                except:
                    print('error_in_print')
            # переносим значения текущего файла в файл с предыдущими данными
            # открывает файл с предыдущими данными на запись
    with open(r'prev_data.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as prev_fl:
        # открываем файл с текущими данными на чтение
        with open(r'current_data.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as cur_fl:
            # записываем в файл с предыдущими файлами то, что прочли из файла с текущими
            prev_fl.write(cur_fl.read())
```

Ответ такой:

```
D:\Other\pycharm\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/Desktop/task/storage.py
---BTC
14CaBzRbZDuGJCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf
31

0.0
error_in_get_total_balance
---ETH
0xd4FD252d7D2C9479a8d616F510eAC6243B5DDdf9
8

0.0
error_in_get_total_balance
---BTC
8Hx9uDuDO98idDfCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf
12

0.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/issues/88

Comment: @gil9red Я так понял, что на той ссылке, которую вы скинули, человек хотел чтобы во время ошибки у него не появлялась ошибка, а выводилась надпись с помощью try/except. Скорее всего я чего то не понял. Как мне исправить ошибку?

Comment: Кст, то, что вы делаете с `class check():` просто жесть, это же не функция -- чтобы код в полях его типа выполнять. У класса лучше создать метод и его вызывать. Либо поменять `class` на `def` и вызывать как честную функцию :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел в код [blockcypher-python](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python) и могу объяснить, что пошло не так в:

```
balance = blockcypher.get_total_balance(k)
```

Вот описание [get_total_balance](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/16c49c0ddeee8bba891b89e0802c92f1d4dcd680/blockcypher/api.py#L310):

```
def get_total_balance(address, coin_symbol='btc', api_key=None):
    return get_address_overview(address=address, coin_symbol=coin_symbol)['final_balance']
```

Вызов [get_address_overview](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/16c49c0ddeee8bba891b89e0802c92f1d4dcd680/blockcypher/api.py#L287) ведет в:

```
def get_address_overview(address, coin_symbol='btc', api_key=None):
    assert is_valid_address_for_coinsymbol(b58_address=address, coin_symbol=coin_symbol)
    ...
```

А там уже происходит проверка в [is_valid_address_for_coinsymbol](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/utils.py#L506), которую ваши данные не прошли:

```
def is_valid_address_for_coinsymbol(b58_address, coin_symbol):
    assert is_valid_coin_symbol(coin_symbol)
    
    if b58_address.startswith(COIN_SYMBOL_MAPPINGS[coin_symbol]['bech32_prefix']):
        return True

    if coin_symbol == 'eth':
        return is_valid_eth_address(b58_address)

    if b58_address[0] in COIN_SYMBOL_MAPPINGS[coin_symbol]['address_first_char_list']:
        if is_valid_address(b58_address):
            return True
    return False
```

**Теперь подробнее:**

Первая проверка с [is_valid_coin_symbol](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/utils.py#L437) должна быть успешной, т.к. вы не передавали свой coin_symbol, а значение **btc** должно успешно пройти проверку, т.к. в [COIN_SYMBOL_SET](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/constants.py#L163) есть значения **btc**, **eth**, ...:

```
def is_valid_coin_symbol(coin_symbol):
    return coin_symbol in COIN_SYMBOL_SET
```

Тут видно использование словаря [COIN_SYMBOL_MAPPINGS](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/constants.py#L186), у него ключом является **coin_symbol** (значения **btc**, **eth**, ...), а значением словарь из значений другого словаря [COIN_SYMBOL_ODICT_LIST](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/constants.py#L3). Поэтому, при вызове `COIN_SYMBOL_MAPPINGS[coin_symbol]['bech32_prefix']` получится значение **bc1**, а `b58_address.startswith('bc1')` провалит проверку, т.к. у вас в `b58_address = "14CaBzRbZDuGJCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf"`.

Следующая проверка [is_valid_eth_address](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/utils.py#L497) не наступит, т.к. `coin_symbol` у вас всегда **btc**. Но если бы для `eth` вы бы заполнили `coin_symbol`, то проверка **не** прошла бы успешно.
Смотрите, у вас там значение адреса `0xd4FD252d7D2C9479a8d616F510eAC6243B5DDdf9`, и оно пройдет проверку длины (без `0x` как раз 40 символов), но завалит проверку `uses_only_hash_chars`, т.к. в ней **учитываются только символы в нижнем регистре**, а в у вас есть в верхнем (по мне это чушь, нужно было сделать проверку регистронезависимой, скорее всего это бага в библиотеки, **можно создать в библиотеке issue**). Поэтому, **я бы рекомендовал** адрес для `eth` приводить в нижний регистр перед тем как вызывать [get_total_balance](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/16c49c0ddeee8bba891b89e0802c92f1d4dcd680/blockcypher/api.py#L310).
Код проверок:

```
HEX_CHARS_RE = re.compile('^[0-9a-f]*$')

def uses_only_hash_chars(string):
    return bool(HEX_CHARS_RE.match(string))

def is_valid_eth_address(addr):
    if addr.startswith('0x'):
        addr = addr[2:].strip()

    if len(addr) != 40:
        return False

    return uses_only_hash_chars(addr)
```

И последняя проверка:

```
    if b58_address[0] in COIN_SYMBOL_MAPPINGS[coin_symbol]['address_first_char_list']:
        if is_valid_address(b58_address):
            return True
```

Давайте посмотрим значения из `COIN_SYMBOL_MAPPINGS[coin_symbol]['address_first_char_list']` для `coin_symbol`:

- `btc`: `('1', '3', '4', 'b')`
- `eth`: `('0')`
  У вас для `btc` значение адреса `14CaBzRbZDuGJCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf`, а первый символ `1`, что **проходит проверку** (`eth` при заполненном `coin_symbol` тоже бы прошел проверку, т.к. начинается на `0x`)

Значит проверка дойдет до [is_valid_address](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/utils.py#L486):

```
def is_valid_address(b58_address):
    if b58_address.startswith('bc1') or b58_address.startswith('ltc1') or b58_address.startswith('tltc1') or b58_address.startswith('tb1'):
        return True
    try:
        return crypto_address_valid(b58_address)
    except:
        return False
```

Сразу видно, что адрес проверку с `.startswith(` код не пройдет, значит будет проверка в [crypto_address_valid](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/utils.py#L481):

```
DIGITS58 = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def decode_base58(bc, length):
    n = 0
    for char in bc:
        n = n * 58 + DIGITS58.index(char)
    try:
        return n.to_bytes(length, 'big')
    except AttributeError:
        return _long_to_bytes(n, length, 'big')

def crypto_address_valid(bc):
    bcbytes = decode_base58(bc, 25)
    return bcbytes[-4:] == sha256(sha256(bcbytes[:-4]).digest()).digest()[:4]
```

Использовал адрес `btc` с `b58_address = '14CaBzRbZDuGJCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf'` с `crypto_address_valid`, получил **успешный результат** и это логично, по вашим логам у того адреса проблем не было:

```
b58_address = '14CaBzRbZDuGJCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf'
bcbytes = decode_base58(b58_address, 25)
print(bcbytes)
# b'\x00#\x18\xa8z[.\xb3\x19;"T\xe3Lo\x0f.\x9fw\xda\xbf\x9e\xd9\xf7"'

print(bcbytes[-4:], sha256(sha256(bcbytes[:-4]).digest()).digest()[:4])
# b'\x9e\xd9\xf7"' b'\x9e\xd9\xf7"'

print(bcbytes[-4:] == sha256(sha256(bcbytes[:-4]).digest()).digest()[:4])
# True
```

Теперь используем адрес, что проверку не прошел:

```
b58_address = '8Hx9uDuDO98idDfCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf'
bcbytes = decode_base58(b58_address, 25)
#  n = n * 58 + DIGITS58.index(char)
#      ValueError: substring not found
```

А причина в символе `O`, которого нет среди **DIGITS58**, возможно это опечатка, т.к. в `DIGITS58` есть `o`, да и в принципе, там похоже каждому латинскому символу предоставляется две формы: в верхнем регистре и нижнем. Предположительно, это бага в этой библиотеки (можно попробовать в вашем окружении зайти в файл `DIGITS58` и добавить туда `O`, чтобы проверить, и если все ок, то создать issue в репозитории библиотеки).
Исключение **ValueError** будет поймано в [is_valid_address](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/eade7e683c7fdf7610b77e7c1d15bebfd64f1164/blockcypher/utils.py#L486) и это сразу приведет к `return False`.

Поэтому адрес `8Hx9uDuDO98idDfCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf` не прошел проверку.

---

**PS.**

Аналогично вы сами можете проверить ошибки для других адресов.

И, конечно, для адресов `etc` нужно передавать соответствующее значение в `get_total_balance`:

```
balance = blockcypher.get_total_balance(k, coin_symbol='etc')
```